# Padding for placeholder without changing the size of input

Tags: css, padding, placeholder, search-form

I do adaptive search form. Search field should take `100%` width of the parent div (the width of the parent div will change depending on the resolution of the device). The button "Search" should always be at the right of the field, do not shift down.

A [working version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMJgW).

But there's a problem: The text "Search now" (placeholder) too close to the edge of the field and I can't move it to the right. In other examples, it moves by the set value for the field padding. But if I change the padding — field itself is shifted to the left, but I only need to move the text!

```css
#searchfield {
   padding: 10px 0 13px 0; /* Try to change the left padding here! All field shifts to the left! But I need only shift the placeholder text to right! */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding text-align:center for id **searchfield**  or add **box-sizing: border-box;** declaration.

try with any one of below examples, it will move the placeholder to right as you expected, these will support Ie lower versions too.

Example1 (using box-sizing:border-box declaration)

```css
#searchfield {
     padding: 10px 0 13px 0px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Example2 (using text-align:center declaration)

```css
#searchfield {
      text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `padding` to move the placeholder text, with the flavor of `box-sizing: border-box;` declaration.

[`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) make user-agents include `padding`/`border` to the `width`/`height` of the box.

```css
#searchfield {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0 13px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* other declarations... */
}
```

*Vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity.*

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;}
#searchfield {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0 13px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#searchsubmit {
  width: 60px;
  height: 41px;
  background: red 0 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="search">
      <form id="searchform" method="get" action="/index.php" _lpchecked="1">
      <input type="text" name="s" id="searchfield" placeholder="Search now">
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
      </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It's worth mentioning that `border-box` [is supported in IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility) as well as modern web browsers.

Comment: Thank You It is so easy to :)

Comment: Never knew to use this, it'll save me a lot of time now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This could do the trick for you. It solved the issue  I was having.
Tried on firefox and chrome

```
.random-class-name{
text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Text written inside the input is indented as well.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use position absolute. try this code:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="search">
      <form id="searchform" method="get" action="/index.php" _lpchecked="1">
      <input type="text" name="s" id="searchfield" placeholder="Search now">
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
      </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>


#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;}
#searchfield {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 13px 20px; /* Try to change the left padding here! All field shifts to the left! But I need only shift the placeholder text to right! 
  position: absolute;*/
  right: 0;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#searchsubmit {
  width: 60px;
  height: 41px;
  background: red 0 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0; 
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

live demo on [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raZGaW)